# Use Load Balancer External IP On Premise

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, flannel, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

Is it possible to use a private IP static for kubernetes External IP type of load balancer? I don't understand it

Comment: Do you want to expose a service using static external IP on premise? Then yes it is possible but you have to expose the service as external IP not as load balancer. We are using that for our on premise cluster. I am currently away from my laptop hence do not have yaml file. I will share it once I get to my laptop.

Comment: @PrafullLadha Thanks guy,I used ingress-nginx and this is issue on https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2984

Comment: Thanks guy,I used ingress-nginx and this is issue on github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2984 on 
@PrafullLadha

Comment: Cool.. glad you found solution